# Prevent multiple Node Express instances

Tags: node.js, express

This is a Windows server with IIS and IISNODE (if that is relevant).

I have the following code in app.ts (simplified)

```
import * as express from "express";
import log from "../util/log";

class App {
    public express: express.Application;

    constructor() {
        this.express = express();
        log.default.info("starting app");
        this.middleware();
    }

    private middleware(): void {
        log.default.info("starting middleware");
        this.express.use((req: IRequest, res: express.Response, next: express.NextFunction) => {
            this.getAllClientConfigurations(req, res, next);
        });

    etc.....
```

When restarting the site in IIS and then hitting it with a request it generates two records of "starting app" in the log file generated by the log script

This causes the middleware() function to be called twice. Inside the middleware function I call another function that sets up some client variables and start up some Cron services which are essential that are running only once.

How can I make sure everything just runs one time?

Comment: Maybe set a flag in `this.express.locals` (http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.locals) and apply middleware only if the flag is not present?

Comment: The question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Why are there multiple App instances? Proceed from there. It's unclear whether a class was instantiated two times within same app or there are 2 app instances.

Comment: @estus "Why are there multiple App instances?" - that is my question in a simpler way :)

Comment: Sadly, nobody knows because you didn't provide enough information. It's unknown how this may be possible in your case. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve is a requirement for code-related questions.

Comment: Any advice on how to find out why there are multiple instances would be appreciated :)